# Import Excel Appointments to Outlook Shared Calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I am trying to import an appointment calendar in Excel with Excel VBA with the following format:

```
Subject        Start            End             Location
Breakfast      8/7/17 9:00 AM   8/7/17 9:30 AM  Cafe
```

I am encountering a *"Run-time Error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method"* at `.Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(NextRow, 2)` when I run this macro:

```
Sub TestCalendar()

Dim OLApp As Object
Dim OLName As Object
Dim OLFolder As Object
Dim OLAppt As Object
Dim NextRow As Long

Set OLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OLName = OLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set OLFolder = OLName.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders("Test")

NextRow = 2

Do Until Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(NextRow, 1)) = ""

Set OLAppt = OLApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

With OLAppt

.Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(NextRow, 1)
.Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(NextRow, 2)
.End = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(NextRow, 3)
.Location = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(NextRow, 4)
.Save
End With

NextRow = NextRow + 1
Loop

Set OLAppt = Nothing
Set OLFolder = Nothing
Set OLName = Nothing
Set OLApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the date is a true date and not text that looks like a date?

Comment: Thanks for your checking. I looked at the format in Excel and it's formatted as Date and not Text.

Comment: Just because the cell is formatted one way does not change if it is text or a date in the cell.  You can format the cell as "Short Date" and type `AAAAAA` and it will remain formatted as "Short Date" but show `AAAAAA`.  If you change the format to "Number" does the value change?  If not it is text and not a date.  Again this is only a guess.

Comment: Noted. I changed to Number format and it gave me 42954.375 for the date above.

Comment: Then it is a date.  and I am at the end of my guessing, sorry.  I hope someone more intelligent can help.

Comment: No worries. It's good to have it checked. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottCraner - *someone more intelligent* ...  really now?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman not high bar, I assure you.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I am saying, just because you don't know what the issue here is does not mean you are more or less intelligent than someone else.

Comment: Okay, `More knowledgeable in this use of vba.` @ScottHoltzman

Comment: @Chris - try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(NextRow, 2).Value2`. Or try `Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(NextRow, 2).Value2,"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")` or whatever format is needed. If that fails, try investigating the format that is needed for that field online or doing a debug.print on an existing occurence of that field, then match. Bottom line is the format needs to be a certain way, you just have to find the exact syntax :)

Comment: @Chris - This code works for me as is after I used your sample data. I admit I did produce the error the at first. Then I changed to early binding (to play with intellisense) and it worked perfect. Then I changed back to late binding and it worked perfect again. I am flummoxed.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I tried both and still getting the same error. I will investigate further. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script worked for me.

```
Sub AddAppointments()
    ' Create the Outlook session
    Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Start at row 2
    r = 2

    Do Until Trim(Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""
        ' Create the AppointmentItem
        Set myApt = myOutlook.CreateItem(1)
        ' Set the appointment properties
        myApt.Subject = Cells(r, 1).Value
        myApt.Location = Cells(r, 2).Value
        myApt.Start = Cells(r, 3).Value
        myApt.Duration = Cells(r, 4).Value
        ' If Busy Status is not specified, default to 2 (Busy)
        If Trim(Cells(r, 5).Value) = "" Then
            myApt.BusyStatus = 2
        Else
            myApt.BusyStatus = Cells(r, 5).Value
        End If
        If Cells(r, 6).Value > 0 Then
            myApt.ReminderSet = True
            myApt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Cells(r, 6).Value
        Else
            myApt.ReminderSet = True
        End If
        myApt.Body = Cells(r, 7).Value
        myApt.Save
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Here's a view of my setup.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ryguy72! Your answer worked, however, what if I want to do this on an outlook shared calendar that I created (say with a name "Test")?

Comment: @chris Use .Add rather than create for a non-default folder